# $or with properties of specific element of array in document

Tags: mongodb, flask-pymongo

```
{
  "deviceId": "A",
  "users": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "status": "ac",
      "DELETE": true
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "status": "ac"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "status": "ac"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "status": "ac"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "status": "deac"
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "status": "ac"
    }
  ]
}
```

i have a document like top and i want to search user by value of status or by DELETE field exists status. But my code not work.

Comment: If your code is not working, show us the code that is not working and tell us what's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Use [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/)

```js
db.test.findOne({
  "deviceId": "A",
  "users": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "id": 1,
      "$or": [
        {
          "DELETE": {
            $exists: true
          }
        },
        {
          "status": "deac"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```